# why bootstrap navbar doesn't set 'active' class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When user clicks an item in navbar, bootstrap doesn't update the 'active' class to the clicked item.

The question is why it's not implemented in bootstrap itself?

I'm new to web dev in general, and new to bootstrap, and am curious what their itention is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap supports the active class for [navbars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav). CSS is static in that you have to manually apply the class to the HTML yourself. So every HTML page you need to add the active class to the link of the current page. This can be done dynamically with PHP, but not with CSS as it is only a styling rule, not a templating rule.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the question is why it's not implemented in bootstrap itself

Comment: It is. The active class is used in the link I provided

Comment: ah yes in Nav, but not in [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) .. confusing names, nav and navbar..

Comment: I can still see the class under navbar `<li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>`

Comment: Of course it isn't. How do you expect your HTML to magically know what page it is on and make that `<li> active`?

Comment: Well, by capturing the 'click' event?

Comment: You will have to do that manually, whether by assigning that class through the DOM/jQuery, or by assigning that class to the `<li>` on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

Because Bootstrap assumes that you are going to navigate to a new page.  When you navigate to a new page any javascript updates to the dom (to set the active class) will only waste time and potentially confuse the user when if they hit the back button.